# Ingresar Saldo (JFRAME CON SQL)

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, poo

Muy buenas tardes a todos, esta es mi primera pregunta en esta pagina, intentaré ser lo mas breve y eficiente con mi pregunta.
Estoy haciendo un proyecto de Banco donde se involucra un metodo que es Ingresar y Sacar dinero.
He escrito un metodo pero me da un error que no habia visto antes y en internet no encuentro como solucionarlo.
El error que aparece es "UnsupportedOperationException"
[image: Metodo Saldo]

```
try{
        String NIF = TxtIngresarNIF.getText();
        String NumCuenta = TxtNumCuenta.getText();
        String Ingreso = TxtDinero.getText();
        if (TxtIngresarNIF.getText().isEmpty()
                ||TxtDinero.getText().isEmpty()
                ||TxtNumCuenta.getText().isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No debe de dejar campos vacios");
        }else{
            double Dinero = Double.parseDouble(Ingreso);
            Cuenta cuen = new Cuenta();
            cuen.ingresardinero(Dinero);
            DaoCl.saldo(cuen);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Saldo Actualizado");
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
        }
```

Mi clase DaoCliente, con el metodo de actualizarSaldo

```
public void saldo(Cuenta cuen) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE cuentas SET SALDO = ? WHERE NIF = ? AND NUMCUENTA = ?");
        ps.setDouble(1, cuen.getSaldo());
        ps.setString(2, cuen.getNIF());
        ps.setString(3, cuen.getNumeroDeCuenta());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
    }
```

Y por ulitmo, en mi clase Cuenta, el metodo para agregar/eliminar Saldo, aunque todavia debo de hacer un controlador para que el usuario no pueda sacar mas dinero del que tiene.

Comment: Buenas, Marco, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Puedes copiar en tu pregunta el volcado de la pila de error que te da? Indica también en qué línea de tu código se está produciendo ese error.

Comment: Hola @RubioRic , lo unico que me imprime es java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.

Comment: Normalmente si ejecutas tu aplicación en un IDE como Eclipse te escribe por consola parte del stack trace de la excepción, indicándote la línea de tu código donde se ha producido originalmente. ¿Eso no te sale por ningún lado? Por otra parte, normalmente en java se ponen los nombres de las variables empezando por minúscula para no confundirlas con los nombres de clases.

Comment: @RubioRic eso pasa cuando la excepción no se captura y acaba el programa, pero aquí la captura y en el `catch` solo muestra en mensaje. Marco, añade la línea `e.printStackTrace()` dentro del `catch` para que te imprima por consola todo el stacktrace, e identifica a que línea se refiere.

Comment: Que bueno, solo parece que pueda ser la llamada al método `ingresarDinero`, cuyo código no has puesto.

Comment: @SJuan76 No me había fijado en el try-catch, daba por supuesto que interrumpía el programa.